# 404 not found for a PDF on my Azure app

Tags: symfony, azure, pdf

I'm currently running my first Symfony app on an Azure server, and I'm running into one a problem concerning a PDF file.

I have a link on my website that points directly to the PDF file (http://[mywebsite].azurewebsites.net/tcbesports.pdf), so that (e.g. in Chrome) it opens in the browser's native pdf reader. This works perfectly fine on my localhost, but when I transferred my app to Azure, the link to the PDF stopped working and I get a 404 not found.

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

However, you can clearly see that I have the file in my folder. Because when I access another file (e.g. http://[mywebsite].azurewebsites.net/favicon.png) that file DOES show up.

[image]

However, robots.txt won't be 'found' either. Does this have something to do with the nature of the file? I've found some mentions of blob files, but had no idea how to go further with that info..

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

If you hit f12 and do a network trace on your website you'll usually see a 404 returned when access a "not normal web" file.

You need to add a mime type for the pdf.

Put the following config.xml in the root of your web.  Yes, event for PHP put a config.xml in the root of your web.  If a config.xml already exists merge the pdf section in.  Note I left a few other types so you can see what a bigger one would look like.  A full list of extensions and their mimeTypes can be found at http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".m4a" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4a" mimeType="audio/mp4a-latm"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".ogg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".pdf" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa